# font size per language

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, unicode

One web page includes 3 different language words such as:

Language / 한국어 / ภาษาไทย

I'd like to enlarge Thai words(ภาษาไทย) in order to highlight it.

```
    <span class="thai">ภาษาไทย</span>
```

Of course, it's possible if I specifiy 'class' property to all Thai sections, but it's too many to put them all.

If possible, I would like to change font-family & font-size according to unicode range with jquery.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not adding the class to container, like `<body>` and use inheritance to set font-size to all the descendant elements. Use `pt` unit to define relative font size.

Comment: @Tushar, The font property can't be assigned to the container such as <body> because <div>Language / 한국어 / ภาษาไทย</div> 3 language words are mixed in a container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string.replace()` to automatically tag every Thai word.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(
   /([\u0E00-\u0E7F]+)/g,
   function (x){return '<span class="thai">'+x+'</span>'}
);
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ndmkaz0g/).

Answer (score 0):

Although no JQuery, I would do something like this:

(In the case of Thai characters, they are in the Unicode range: 0E00-0E7F)

```
function StyleThaiInTag(tagName) {
  var allTags = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
  for (var i = 0; i < allTags.length; i++) {
    var element = allTags[i];
    var code = element.innerHTML.charCodeAt(0) 
    if (0x0E00 <= code && code <= 0x0E7F) {
       // style element the way you want
       element.style.fontSize = "2em";
       //...
    }
  }  
}

// example usage:
StyleThaiInTag('span');
StyleThaiInTag('div');
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r5cfh8ao/).

Comment: I'd rather use @Rafi code because your code doesn't work if sring starts with English alphabet. Anyway, thank you.